# How to parse a ZoneDateTime format?

Tags: postgresql

I'm currently trying to parse a timestamp that looks like: `2020-08-03T11:37:42.529Z[UTC]`

This timestamp was generated with Java's [ZoneDateTime](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html) data type

What I have already tried was to parse it via:

```
SELECT '2020-08-03T11:37:42.529Z[UTC]'::timestamp with time zone;
```

But that would fail with an exception (unless I parse up until timezone Z).

**Edit**
For clarification, this is currently a String that is saved in a file, so this application has no direct interaction with Java.

Comment: What are you passing a String anyway? Can't you pass an instance of a `ZonedDateTime` to your SQL statement? Can you show us the complete context (=Java code) where you are doing this? (**[edit]** your question, please do not post code or additional information in comments)

Comment: hello @a_horse_with_no_name , I have updated my question accordingly. This is only a String, as the Java application has no interaction with the postgres db for this context

Comment: If there is no interaction with the database, then how can you run a SELECT statement?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name The Java application writes data into a file, and then the files are loaded into the DB as string. The next step is how to transform the string or best-case save it in the right data type from the first step

Comment: How are you loading those files into the database? Can't you do the parsing at that step?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As explained by Adrian, the below code (using `at time zone`) does not really work. The only other alternative I can think of is to replace the timezone abbreviation with a proper offset. To do that, a function is probably the easiest solution:

```sql
create or replace function replace_tz_abbrev(p_input text)
  returns text
as
$$
declare
  l_offset_hours text;
  l_tz_abbrev text;
begin
  l_tz_abbrev := substring(p_input from '\[([A-Z]+)\]');
  
  select to_char(utc_offset, 'hh24:mi') 
    into l_offset_hours
  from pg_catalog.pg_timezone_abbrevs
  where abbrev = l_tz_abbrev;
  
  return regexp_replace(p_input, '\[[A-Z]+\]', l_offset_hours);
end;
$$
language plpgsql;
```

This is a rough sketch, the function needs some error checking in case the abbreviation doesn't exist. Maybe checking `pg_timezone_names` as a fallback to deal with names like `Europe/Berlin`.

The result of replace_tz_abbrev() can be cast to a `timestamptz` (at least with the given example). This can either be done in the function itself (and changing it to `returns timestamptz` or when calling it.

---

**The below is not correct**
(I'll just leave it here for reference, so that the comments

<strike>One way I can think of is to extract the time zone from the string and use it together with the `to_timestamp()` function:</strike>

```
with data (input) as (
  values ('2020-08-03T11:37:42.529Z[UTC]')
)
select to_timestamp(input, 'yyyy-mm-dd"T"hh24:mi:ss.ms') at time zone substring(input from '\[([A-Z]+)\]') 
from data;
```

Comment: The problem with above is the first part will rotate UTC time to local time with time zone at whatever ```TimeZone``` is set to and then use to rotate to UTC. So here in ```PDT``` I get: ```SELECT to_timestamp('2020-08-03T11:37:42.529Z[UTC]', 'yyyy-mm-ddThh24:mi:ss.ms') at time zone substring('2020-08-03T11:37:42.529Z[UTC]' from '\[([A-Z]+)\]') ; 08/03/2020 18:37:42.529 ```

Comment: @AdrianKlaver: hmm, you are right. So I guess there is no way to do this in SQL. It's really a shame, that `to_timestamp()` can't deal with time zone, only offsets.

Comment: Yeah that would be nice. My fallback is Python dateutil. In particular: ```from dateutil.parser import parse parse('2020-08-03T11:37:42.529Z[UTC]', fuzzy=True).isoformat()  '2020-08-03T11:37:42.529000+00:00'``` Where ```fuzzy``` ignores extraneous tokens in the string.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the timestamp string always ends with `[timezone]` then:

```
select regexp_replace('2020-08-03T11:37:42.529Z[UTC]', '\[[^\]]*\]', '')::timestamp with time zone;
       regexp_replace        
-----------------------------
 08/03/2020 04:37:42.529 PDT
```

Where `regexp_replace()` replaces the `[timezone]` with an empty string and then you cast the `2020-08-03T11:37:42.529Z`  portion to a timestamp with time zone.

Answer (score 0):

You can't directly convert this format to a timestamp with timezone. if you are allowed to manipulate the string to get the timedate separtly from the timezone you can do this:

```
select  TIMESTAMP 'The date and time go here'AT TIME ZONE 'timezone name or abbreviation go here';
select  TIMESTAMP '2020-08-03T11:37:42.529'AT TIME ZONE 'Africa/Dar_es_Salaam';
select  TIMESTAMP '2020-08-03T11:37:42.529'AT TIME ZONE 'UTC';
```

The reason you have to split the string is that like you discovered a simple conversion  does not work and the function TO_TIMESTAMP() that allows you to specify the format does not support specifiying in the format that the string will contain a timezone, only a time offset (example: -03 hours).

```
-- No way to include the timezone name in the format param.
-- if you insist to add 'TZ'or 'tz' you will get "ERROR:  "TZ"/"tz"/"OF" format patterns are not supported in to_date"
select TO_TIMESTAMP('2020-08-03T11:37:42.529Z[UTC]','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.MS')
```

The difference between the a timezone and a time offset is also why you might not want to do what you are trying to do, postgres does not store timezones (or time offsets). Instead it converts to UTC, and later on reads the column as UTC if the column is 'timestamp without timezone', if the column is 'timestamp with timezone' it converts from UTC to what ever the current session is set to. if you care about the timezone you should store it in another column.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name thanks, I skimmed the wrong part of the docs.